# How to use splinter to fill up an input box inside a table?

Tags: python, html, forms, testing, splinter

I have a html structure as following:

```
    <table id="Table1" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 52px; WIDTH: 407px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 53px" width="407" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px">Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="TextBox1" id="TextBox1" style="width:153px;" type="text"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px">Password</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="TextBox2" id="TextBox2" style="width:153px;" type="password"></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Button1" value="Login" id="Button1" style="width:68px;" type="submit"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px"></td>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px; height: 20px;"><a href="signinup.aspx">Sign up</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px">
                        <a href="changepassword.aspx">Change Password</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px"><a href="RetrievePassword.aspx">Retrieve Password</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 102px"></td>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
```

I would like to access the input box having ID TextBox1 and TextBox2 and fill them up with username and password.

I am doing following (for example):

```
browser.fill('TextBox1', 'John')
```

But it returns me with an error:

```
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "TextBox1"
```

Can anyone help on this? (I am using splinter for the first time)

Comment: It works! Add complete example so we can help

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk I added the complete example, let me know what is missing?

Comment: I've recreated the case and it works. Try this out: http://pastebin.com/WDUjgzvL (/home/x/example.html is a HTML that you've posted). It will fill the form. So I guess you have an error somewhere else, that's why I need more details.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrDawidiuk, you are right. I also tried the particular html and used that only to apply browser.fill() function. It works! but, the same thing does not work when I try it at http://tool.cohmetrix.com/.
Can you kindly try and tell me why the error occurs in such case? Is it because its inside a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in your comments, the problem stems from the frame that the box is wrapped in. Get around it like this:

```
browser.visit(browser.find_by_tag('frame')[0]['src'])
browser.fill('TextBox1', 'John')
```

Comment: Thank you, what is that index for?

Comment: Well, `find_by_tag` always returns a list, so index 0 to return the first or only one. Could you upvote the answer if it helped you? :)